# Getting session value, Order_id and order_amount in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

how to get session value, Order_id and order_amount, order_currency, customer_receipt_email  in Magento 2.2

Can I show this in a external php file? / Or how I can test it ?

Answer (score 0):

I must tell you there are multiple ways of getting the information you need, each the approach depending on what you need it for or where you need this

The following will get you all the information you need

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId())
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); 
    $products = [];

    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer_email= $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); 
    } else {
        $customer_email= ''; 
    }

    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $products[] = [
            'id'=>$item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'price' =>$item->getPrice(),
            'quantity' =>intval($item->getQtyOrdered()) 
        ]; 
    }  
?>


<?php echo $customer_email; ?>
<?php echo json_encode($products); ?>
<?php echo $block->getOrderId(); ?>
```

Please let me know if you need more explanatory

I have done something like this, pull the project and use you, you're welcome to pull the project as you please and modify, you probably may not need to do much just add extra field remove the one not needed depending on your bank requirement https://github.com/emmaajoku/Zenith-payment-gateway-for-Magento-2-master

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel Ajoke. Basically what I need that is: I've a bank api where I pass the session data, order id, order currency and order amount . that site is a php site. So, how can I pass  these value to that site for online bank transaction?